# How can I pass parameter from js to direct events Url Action?

Tags: javascript, c#, ext.net

Is there a way to get objectId parameter from js and send it as parameter to Url action?

JS:

```
function ButtonClick(objectId) {
    App.testID.fireEvent("click", objectId);
}
```

Ext.net:

```
Html.X().ID("testID").DirectEvents
(
    de =>
    {
        de.Click.Url = Url.Action("TestMethod", "TestController");
        de.Click.ExtraParams.Add(new Parameter("objectId", "I need objectId here"));
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with diferent solution when I saw compiled code in debugger.
You can create direct event like this:

```
Html.X().ID("testID")
.Listeners
(
    l =>
    {
        l.AfterRender.Handler = @"App.testID.on('testEvent', function(id) {
                                                                             Ext.net.directRequest({
                                                                                url: '/TestController/TestMethod',
                                                                                extraParams:
                                                                                {
                                                                                    'objectId': id
                                                                                }
                                                                            });
                                                                        });";
    }
)
```

And fire it with:

```
function ButtonClick(objectId) {
    App.testID.fireEvent("testEvent", objectId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the raw code as the value string and add `ParameterMode.Raw` to the `Parameter` instance, like this:

```
de.Click.ExtraParams.Add(new Parameter("objectId", "App.MyComponent.Id", ParameterMode.Raw));
```

(based on [Examples Explorer - Layouts > CardLayout](https://mvc4.ext.net/#/Layout_CardLayout/Basic/))

Or alternatively, a custom object:

```
de.Click.ExtraParams.Add(new
{
    myTargetId = JRawValue.From("this.up('button').id")
});
```

(based on [Examples Explorer - Models > Data Annotations](https://mvc4.ext.net/#/Models/Data_Annotations/))